Query Metadata of Partitions
Given this partitioned table, how can I query the time ranges for which partitions have been defined for the measurement table?
In particular, I'd like to know that measurement's partitions' timestamps range from 2006-02-01 through 2006-04-01.
postgres=# CREATE TABLE measurement (
postgres(#     city_id         int not null,
postgres(#     logdate         date not null,
postgres(#     peaktemp        int,
postgres(#     unitsales       int
postgres(# ) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# CREATE TABLE measurement_y2006m02 PARTITION OF measurement
postgres-#     FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-02-01') TO ('2006-03-01');
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# CREATE TABLE measurement_y2006m03 PARTITION OF measurement
postgres-#     FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-03-01') TO ('2006-04-01');
CREATE TABLE


Run \dt+ measurement in psql.

Check this (rather old) answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206515/dealing-with-out-of-range-values-on-a-partition-by-range
